Generating the space of spherical polynomials from isotropic vectors
Let $\Delta \equiv -\left(\partial_{x_{1}}^{2} + \cdots + \partial_{x_{n}}^{2}\right)$ be the usual Laplacian on $\mathbb{R}^n$:

Recall that a polynomial $\operatorname{f}\in\mathbb{C}\left[x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right]$ is called spherical if $\Delta \operatorname{f} = 0$.
Let $H_{k}$ be the space of homogeneous spherical polynomials of degree $k$ in $\mathbb{C}\left[x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right]$.
We say that a vector $z \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$ ( viewed as a column vector ) is isotropic if
$$
z^{t} \cdot z = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}z_{i}^{2} = 0
$$
A simple calculation shows that for $\xi \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$ isotropic,
$$
\operatorname{P}_{\xi,k}\left(x\right) :=\left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\xi_{i}x_{i}\right)^{k} \in H_{k}
$$

Q: For a fix $k$, how do we prove ( or see quickly ) that the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space generated by all the $\operatorname{P}_{\xi,k}\left(x\right)$, for $\xi$ isotropic, equals $H_{k}$ ?.

This is exercise 5 on page 133 of "Partial Differential Equations II" by M. Taylor. The fact follows from the invariance of $H_k$ under $SO(n)$ and the nontrivial fact that the eigenspace $H_k$ has no proper subspaces invariant under $SO(n)$.

Yes, the irreducibility of $H_k$ as an $SO(n)$-module might be the simplest way of proving what I was looking for.
